# MySQL change root default password on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos

I tried changing MySQL root password right after installing it. Now on terminal, it says to check out some newer query `ALERT USER`. I checked the documentation, but it's still the old query `CHANGE PASSWORD`

Any help please

Comment: Ok i found a way to change the root password from workbench
i just clicked on "local instance 3306" in the home page and gave me a choice to change password !

Comment: Do you still have a question? If so please edit to make clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a way to change the root password from workbench i just clicked on "local instance 3306" in the home page and gave me a choice to change root password, it's even easier than changing it from the terminal !

Answer (score 1):

instruction that worked with my case.

mysql -uroot -p (default root password is blank with brew install)

1. use mysql;
2. ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';

That's it. ( Mac M1 MacBook, mysql installed with brew, mysql version 8.0.28 for macos12.0 on arm64 (Homebrew) )

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has trouble with the `mysql -u root -p` command but know the current MySQL password and has MySQL Workbench installed, just try to start a command line client by right clicking your localhost connection in MySQL Workbench:

[image]

Once the command line client started, enter your current MySQL password when prompted in terminal. After that, use the `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password'` command.

Using Mac M1 MacBook and mysql version 8.0.30